# "CLT implies LLN?"

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

By the central limit theorem we have that for a an iid sequence $X_i$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ that,

$$\sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{X}_n-\mu}{\sigma}\rightarrow_d N(0,1)$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$

But this also implies that for sufficiently large $n$ we have approximately,

$$  \overline{X}_n \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/n) $$

And as $n \rightarrow\infty$ we have $\overline{X}_n \sim N(\mu,0)=\mu$

So we have $P(\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}\overline{X}_n=\mu)=1$. Which would mean that the CLT implies the LLN. This reasoning is probably false since the convergence for the CLT is weak. But still it seems plausible since the limiting distribution will just be a constant.  Can someone point out what is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: The "So we have..." is a non-sequitur.   The CLT gives info about the limit of certain probabilities, not the probability of a limit.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes you're right! I corrected it.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks for the reaction, so what about the weaker convergence in probability then?

Comment: Yeah, the argument is a good motivation for a relation between the two results, but the moving of the limit inside the probability is not allowed.

Comment: I think this can help. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/549450

Comment: SLLN does not require existence of second moments. So CLT cannot give us he full force of SLLN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\xrightarrow{d}N(0, \sigma^2)$, then for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(|\bar{X}_n-\mu|> \epsilon)=\mathsf{P}(|\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)|> \sqrt{n}\epsilon)\to 0.
$$
as $n\to\infty$. That is, $\bar{X}_n\xrightarrow{p}\mu$.

---

As for the a.s. convergence assume, in addition, that $v_3:=\mathsf{E}|X_1|^3<\infty$. Then, using a non-uniform Berry-Esseen bound for i.i.d. sequences,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(|\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)|> \sqrt{n}\epsilon)&\le 2\sum_{n\ge 1}\bar{\Phi}\!\left(\sqrt{n}\epsilon/\sigma\right)+\frac{Cv_3}{(1+(\sqrt{n}\epsilon/\sigma)^3)\sqrt{n}} \\
&\le 2\int_0^{\infty}\bar{\Phi}\!\left(\sqrt{x}\epsilon/\sigma\right)+\frac{Cv_3}{(1+(\sqrt{x}\epsilon/\sigma)^3)\sqrt{x}}dx \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}+\frac{C8\sqrt{3}\pi \sigma v_3}{\epsilon}<\infty,
\end{align}
where $C>0$ is a constant. That is, $\mathsf{P}(|\bar{X}_n-\mu|> \epsilon\text{ i.o.})=0$.

Comment: SLLN does not require existence of second moments. So CLT cannot give us he full force of SLLN. For OP's sake let me add that $F_n \to F$ in distribution and $F$ continuous implies that $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ uniformly.

Comment: Also for the SLLN we don't need the "i.i.d." assumption. Pairwise independence and "i.d." suffice.

Comment: So the clt does imply the WLLN!

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising Under the conditions needed for the CLT, the WLLN holds as well.

Comment: That is true but the same assumptions also imply the SLLN and that can’t be shown by the clt as was pointed out in the comments.

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising Actually, you can show that using the B-C lemma. For example, if $\{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\}$ are sub-Gaussian, it is easy to show that the events $\{|\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)|>\sqrt{n}\epsilon\}$, $i\ge 1$, are summable.

Comment: So with the inclusion of the BC-lemma the argument would actually be correct?

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising Kind of. However, I am not sure if we can avoid additional conditions on the tail of the distribution of $X_1$.